# Fade in elements when they come into viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velocity.js

I'm trying to fade in elements with the class of "fade-me" whenever those elements come into view. I found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qad/ and it does this exact thing, however it adds the opacity value repeatedly to the elements that come into view. This create a looping animation if I'm trying to use Velocity's transition slideUpIn instead of opacity. So I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).velocity('transition.slideUpIn', { stagger: 700 }).delay(1000)     
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

It works but it it loops the SlideUpIn animation. How do I make it run animation only once on that element that comes into view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle a CSS class as indicator and then check for it:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $doc = $(document);
var $hideMe = $('.hideme');

$doc.ready(function () {

    $window.scroll(function () {
        var bottom_of_window = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();

        $hideMe.each(function (i) {
            var $elm = $hideMe.eq(i);
            var bottom_of_object = $elm.offset().top + $elm.outerHeight();

            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                if (!$elm.hasClass('in-viewport')) {
                    $elm.addClass('in-viewport');
                    $elm.velocity('transition.slideUpIn', { stagger: 700 }).delay(1000);
                }
            } else {
                $elm.removeClass('in-viewport');
            }
        }); 

    });

});
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. How can I trigger the function only once on each element? So if that element came in view at some point, the function shouldn't run on it again.

Comment: Remove the last `else { ... }` then it will not trigger again.